# Comprehensive list of ECO codes together with the list of moves

Tags: opening

I am looking for a comprehensive list of ECO codes with various variations together with a corresponding list of moves. Basically something like:

```
B01 Scandinavian (centre counter) defence 1. e4 d5
B01 Scandinavian defence, Lasker variation 1. e4 d5 2. exd5 Qxd5 3. Nc3 Qa5 4. d4 Nf6 5. Nf3 Bg4 6. h3
B01 Scandinavian defence 1. e4 d5 2. exd5 Qxd5 3. Nc3 Qa5 4. d4 Nf6 5. Nf3 Bf5
```

The best I was able to find is [this resourse](http://www.365chess.com/eco.php), but it is kind of bad, because all they can give me about Sicilian is this:

```
B20-B99 Sicilian defence1. e4 c5
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here](http://sourceforge.net/p/scid/code/ci/master/tree/scid.eco) is the file used by [Scid](http://scid.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Wow, super cool